# Getting a KeyError with celery when trying to run a task

Tags: python, celery

I'm trying to run a celery task but am receiving a `KeyError` I'm guessing it's because celery is trying to get my `tasks.py` file from chatbot.tasks.add. However me being stupid I put the add() module in my local bot/tasks directory. Which is what is causing the error. I thought I could fix this problem by just instead doing `from chatbot.tasks import add` when I'm in my Python shell but I keep getting a "no module named..." error.

So how do I successfully pass the correct key (chatbot.tasks.add) to celery in the shell now?

EDIT:
Traceback Error:

```
[2018-02-13 04:32:47,609: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2018-02-13 04:32:47,628: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2018-02-13 04:32:48,641: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2018-02-13 04:32:48,674: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@Charles-PC ready.
[2018-02-13 04:33:52,023: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'bot.tasks.add'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
Please see --- for more information.

The full contents of the message body was:
{'timelimit': (None, None), 'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': (2, 3), 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'bot.tasks.add
075-4bb0-89e5-b33a545c11f4'} (213b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\elitebook\.virtualenvs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer.py", line 455, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body,
KeyError: 'bot.tasks.add'
```

Comment: That's not a key. If you get an error, you should post the actual message and full traceback.

Comment: hey sorry, posted the traceback. thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your application layout but in my celery project (which is almost 3 years old) I have two files: **celeryconfig.py** and **celery.py**. Within **celery.py** I am importing all my tasks so I can then refer to them from other packages that import my project or when I want to run celery beat task.